# Unity : WebGL + Mobile + Sound?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, audio, unity-webgl

The music and sound effects I have don't play when the game is played on mobile via WebGL. Is this something I can fix or is that strictly a Mobile + WebGL issue? I have gotten sound to play on WebGL via desktop, just not via iOS.

I know this question is better asked on the Unity forums, but I never seem to get an answer there.

Comment: This is really a know issue that is not yet solved. I personally think that it is a waste of time to make games for mobile webgl due to many issues that occurs when you attempt to do so. Unity webgl is mature enough to run on mobile devices, you should spend your time somewhere else. You may need to build a [Javascript plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) to fix this or use a plugin to play the sound. See [this](https://paulbakaus.com/tutorials/html5/web-audio-on-ios/) post.

Comment: Yeah, I know WebGL + Mobile is not the ideal way to do things right now. But I was hired to make a game that can be played on a web browser via iPad. I'm not familiar enough with JavaScript to make any kind of cohesive experience, so Unity was my best option.

Comment: Well then with Unity you will have hard times for iOS. Note that you can make a plugin with JavaScript like I mentioned above and use it to play sound in Unity. That is complicated but possible.